# how to import xls to database with asp.net 4.0 with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel

I just want to make `xls` mapping facility with asp.net 4.0 with `C#`. I just want to import all details from Excel `sheet1` to database.

Here I am binding one repeater which have text box here user can enter specific row to table column and make it to do `xls mapping`.

#### My Code:

```
 protected void lbut_import_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            if (FileUpload1.FileContent.Length > 0)
            {
                string Foldername;
                string Extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                string filename = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss");
                if (Extension == ".XLS" || Extension == ".XLSX" || Extension == ".xls" || Extension == ".xlsx")
                {
                    Foldername = Server.MapPath("~/Files/");
                    FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Foldername + filename + Extension);
                    String conStr = "";
                    switch (Extension)
                    {
                        case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                            conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                            "Data Source=" + Foldername + "//" + filename + Extension + ";" +
                            "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
                            break;

                        case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
                            conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                            "Data Source=" + Foldername + "//" + filename + Extension + ";" +
                            "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
                            break;
                    }
                    OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [Sheet1$]", excelConnection);
                    excelConnection.Open();
                    OleDbDataReader dReader;
                    dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRMConnectionString"].ToString());
                    //Give your Destination table name
                    using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
                    {
                        sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "tbl_Party_master";
                        sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Name",dReader[int.Parse(txt_col.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                        sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("type_id", dReader[int.Parse(txt_col1.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col2.Text.Trim()))
                        {
                            sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Ownername", dReader[int.Parse(txt_col2.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                        }
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col3.Text.Trim()))
                        {
                            sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Ownermob", dReader[int.Parse(txt_col3.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                        }
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col4.Text.Trim()))
                        {
                            sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Room", dReader[int.Parse(txt_col4.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                        }
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col5.Text.Trim()))
                        {
                            sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Road", dReader[int.Parse(txt_col5.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                        }
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col6.Text.Trim()))
                        {
                            sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Area", dReader[int.Parse(txt_col6.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                        }
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col7.Text.Trim()))
                        {
                            sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("City", dReader[int.Parse(txt_col7.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                        }
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col8.Text.Trim()))
                        {
                            sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Mobile", dReader[int.Parse(txt_col8.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                        }
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col9.Text.Trim()))
                        {
                            sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Email", dReader[int.Parse(txt_col9.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                        }
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col10.Text.Trim()))
                        {
                            sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("ContactPerson", dReader[int.Parse(txt_col10.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                        }
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col11.Text.Trim()))
                        {
                            sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("ContactPersonmob", dReader[int.Parse(txt_col11.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                        }
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col12.Text.Trim()))
                        {
                            sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("UserOFC", dReader[int.Parse(txt_col12.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                        }
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col13.Text.Trim()))
                        {
                            sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("UserVAT", dReader[int.Parse(txt_col13.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                        }
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col14.Text.Trim()))
                        {
                            sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("UserINV", dReader[int.Parse(txt_col14.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                        }
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col15.Text.Trim()))
                        {
                            sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("UserNone", dReader[int.Parse(txt_col15.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                        }
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col16.Text.Trim()))
                        {
                            sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("state_id", dReader[int.Parse(txt_col16.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                        }
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col17.Text.Trim()))
                        {
                            sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("country_id", dReader[int.Parse(txt_col17.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                        }
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_col18.Text.Trim()))
                        {
                            sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Remark",dReader[int.Parse(txt_col18.Text.Trim())].ToString());
                        }
                        sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Register_Date", System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
                        sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("User_id", db.Users.Where(u => u.Username.Equals((String)Session["Username"])).Select(u => u.Ref_no).SingleOrDefault());
                        sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
                        excelConnection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            ibtnimexls_ModalPopupExtender.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

But this code is giving me one error:
`there is no specific row/column at drreader[] object.`

here i put complete error message from iis:

```
Server Error in '/CRM' Application.

No data exists for the row/column.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: No data exists for the row/column.

Source Error: 


Line 3121:                        {
Line 3122:                            sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "tbl_Party_master";
Line 3123:                            sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", dReader[int.Parse(((TextBox)Repeater_Column_List.Items[0].FindControl("txt_col")).Text.Trim())].ToString());
Line 3124:                            sqlBulk.ColumnMappings.Add("type_id", dReader[int.Parse(((TextBox)Repeater_Column_List.Items[1].FindControl("txt_col")).Text.Trim())].ToString());
Line 3125:                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(((TextBox)Repeater_Column_List.Items[2].FindControl("txt_col")).Text.Trim()))

Source File: f:\CRM\Staff\Raise_Ticket.aspx.cs    Line: 3123 

Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: No data exists for the row/column.]
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.DoValueCheck(Int32 ordinal) +1106519
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.GetValue(Int32 ordinal) +12
   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader.get_Item(Int32 index) +10
   Staff_Raise_Ticket.lbut_import_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in f:\CRM\Staff\Raise_Ticket.aspx.cs:3123
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +113
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +9
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +176
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1

Please help me!
```

### Update

here is my repeater html markup :

```
 <table>
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                    <td><strong>Table Data Column</strong></td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td><strong>Excel Column Number</strong></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tr>
                                    <td><asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="Name" Enabled="false" Checked="true"/></td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>
                                     <ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender16" runat="server" TargetControlID="txt_col" WatermarkText="Enter Row number">
                                     </ajaxToolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                                     <ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender7" runat="server" TargetControlID="txt_col" FilterType="Numbers"></ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_col" runat="server" CssClass="input" MaxLength="4"></asp:TextBox>
                                     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required" ControlToValidate="txt_col" ValidationGroup="ImportXLS" Enabled="true" Display="None" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>                                
                                     <ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender7" runat="server" TargetControlID="RequiredFieldValidator6" WarningIconImageUrl="~/images/Warning.gif" CloseImageUrl="~/images/close.gif" >
                                     </ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    ..............
                                    </table>
```

Comment: downwaters please make comment if u found something strange here.

Comment: I find it strange that a) you have not included the exact exception details and b) you have not indicated which line this is thrown from. My guess is you haven't attempted to debug this yourself and instead expect someone else to.

Comment: oh sorry i made update.

Comment: Your update doesn't show which line throws the exception. When you know which line throws, you will know which index you are passing to `dReader` and can then compare that to the number of columns returned by your query.

Comment: Right, so the problem line is 3123. When you debug, which index are you trying to access? i.e. What number does `int.Parse(((TextBox)Repeater_Column_List.Items[0].FindControl("txt_col")).Text.Trim())` return? After that, do you have a column in your result set at that index?

Comment: can i have to iterate with for each loop RepeaterItem and fix it up.

Comment: it does.t return number.

Comment: @DanielKelley - i just want ur solution.

Comment: I really can't help you any more. When you call `dReader[x]`, `x` must be an integer that represents an index in the reader. If you don't supply a valid one to the call it won't work. Short of sitting next to debug this for you I can't help.

Comment: ya i put Add Watch and i see that was return 1 that was entered into first text box.

Comment: Now i change method fro passing it like : int.Parse(dReader[((TextBox)Repeater_Column_List.Items[0].FindControl("txt_col")).Text.Trim()].ToString())); and now i'm getting something new error. see update

Comment: What is Repeater_Column_List? Is this a repeater on the page? This and your not understanding it is where all of your problems are coming from.

Comment: now can u understand with updated question.

Comment: @matt_lethargic - ya can u understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WOW!! I'm a bit lost for words TBH. Why not write each text box onto the html and not dynamically create everything in a repeater? This is where your problem is. When you post back the repeater loses its databinding and then when you try and reference rows in the Repeater they are all null because you have no data binded to it after the postback.

This is kinda a guess, but a well informed one. Unless you have some crazy business case for doing so I urge you to not continue using the repeater and write each textbox by hand.

Now I must go find a bin to be sick in! ;-)

Comment: i use ur technique as you suggested but still there is error occurs in ur scenario.

Comment: Because you did something wrong! If you have a new problem, then post a question showing your code and the error that you are getting and I'm sure it'll get fixed.

Comment: i write each text box by hand but still error occurs

Comment: I've given up now btw, there's no helping some people.